# How to use Related Function of excel into power bi

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I tried to use related function in power bi as my date reference is giving error type issue. i am  using excel query in power bi Dax.

```
=if(related('Date Reference'[Week])=IES_Sales_report[Week],"TW" ,"")
```

Comment: The prerequisite is your tables "IES_Sales_report" and "date Reference" has to related using a joining column. are they? Show the error message you are getting.

Comment: Is this a calculated column or a measure?